# can i give project name as hello_world in wamp 3

Tags: apache, wamp

i used wamp 2 and now installed wamp 3, in wamp 2 project name was like hello_world but in wamp 3 getting error. i added virtual host in host file like - 
httpd-hosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/hello_world"
    ServerName project1
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/hello_world">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 hello_world
::1 hello_world
```

why i am getting error? please help.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: The ServerName hello_world has syntax error in file c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/hello_world
    ServerName hello_world
   <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/hello_world">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

127.0.0.1 hello_world
::1 hello_world

Answer (score 1):

Your `ServerName` is `project1`

```
ServerName project1
```

So your HOSTS file need to define an IP for this domain

HOSTS file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

127.0.0.1 project1
::1 project1
```

Also dont forget you also need `localhost` in the hosts file as well

Once changed you will need to restart the dnscache.

```
(right click) wampmanager-> Tools-> Restart DNS
```

#### Alternatively

Change the ServerName, **but dont use the `_` character in a domain name, its not valid**. Try replacing it with a `-`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/hello-world"
    ## change the domain name
    ServerName hello_world

    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/hello-world">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I changed server name.
and restarted DNS but no luck.
I am getting this error message - The ServerName hello_world has syntax error in file c:/wamp64/bin/apache/apache2.4.23/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

project is running successfully, only i am getting the above error message on localhost page.

Comment: Then you had better add your current `httpd-vhosts.co‌​nf` file to your question

Comment: # Virtual Hosts


<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
 <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
  Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
  AllowOverride All
  Require local
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>




<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/hello_world
    ServerName hello_world
   <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/hello_world">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: That error message normally give a line number. What line is it complaining about

Comment: at -  ServerName hello_world

Comment: Silly me :) It's been staring me in the face all the time. The `_` character is not a valid character in a domain name! Use `hello-world`